# Delete same records on some columns usin NOT IN statement in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table like below:

[image]

which contains same records on **session_id, user_id, quiz_id, question_id** columns.
So, I want to keep only one of them and remove others. And I tried below query:

```
DELETE FROM su_submitted_answers WHERE `id` NOT IN (SELECT id from su_submitted_answers GROUP BY session_id, user_id, quiz_id, question_id );
```

but query does not affect any record. Also there is no NULL value in ID column.

[image]

Solution to my situation is also necessary but "why above query did not work" is essential question. Thanks for any help.

Comment: '"why above query did not work" ' - because NOT IN (SELECT id from su_submitted_answers GROUP BY session_id, user_id, quiz_id, question_id ); is never true. BTW group by without aggregate function will error if only_full_group_by is true..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use multiple-table DELETE:

```
DELETE t1
FROM su_submitted_answers t1
JOIN su_submitted_answers t2 ON (t1.session_id, t1.user_id, t1.quiz_id, t1.question_id) = (t2.session_id, t2.user_id, t2.quiz_id, t2.question_id)
WHERE t1.id < t2.id
```

This query will delete all rows duplicated by the mentioned columns except one of these rows with greatest `id` value.